# Formal definition of a "class of functions"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I see this phrase get thrown around a lot, but I am struggling to find an actual definition for a class of functions.

If there is no formal definition and "class" is an inherently vague term, can someone give me examples of attributes of functions that one might use to separate functions into classes?

As a simple example of what I mean by this, linear and quadratic functions are in their respective "classes."

Comment: Maybe if you specify the discipline?  Algebra, topology, functional analysis, etc.  If there's enough structure to the subject at hand --- maybe it's clear they're a subset of a vector space of functions, or such a class would inherit particular topological properties, or they're closed under certain operations ---  it might be enough in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As used here, "class" is an informal notion: a collection of objects that are distinguished by some property shared by its members.  That property could be anything.